# Loading portion of site into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, load, src

I have a script which loads content into a iframe using:

```
document.GetElementById('iframeid').src = 'site.html';
```

Now, the problem is that I want only a portion of the page loaded. If I could use jQuery I would specify which part by:

```
$('#iframeid').load(src = 'site.html .classforportion');
```

However if seems like jQuery .load doesn't work for iframes.

Is it possible to 'fool' the browser into grabbing the contents of a variable or a function for the first case? Or is it possible to create temporary 'html'-files only for so long that the script would load the right contents into it and pass it to an iframe (hm... seems unlikely...).

A work around solution for this specific case would be removing the first line of the loaded page. Is that possible with javascript or jQuery? Is it possible for this situation involving the iframe?

Thanks, going crazy over this thing! So, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive never heard of a way of doing this with javascript since you cannot access files outside your own domain with javascript. You can do like this with PHP

```
<?php
function get_content_part($part=null, $website = null) 
{
$website = file_get_contents($website);
$data = str_replace("\n", '', $website);
echo preg_match("/\<div class\=\"'.$part.'\"\>(.*)<\/div\>/",$data,$match);
return $match;
}
?>
```

Maybe integrate this with a javascript Ajax call and you can do it by javascript calls.
Best regards
Jonas

Comment: That is good stuff Jonas m! I was thinking about using PHP but wasn't really able to visualize how to go about doing it though! This worked fine (with some modifications)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the problem is that I want only a portion of the page loaded

Load page into the invisible container (iframe, div, etc..) or in a javascript string variable and do whatever you want to do with it. For example, load partial content into invisible div and than copy it into iframe or load the hole page into invisible iframe and then copy the part you need into another, visible one.

Comment: True. Jonas M posted a nice way to handle the problem though!

Comment: @Matte         could it be easier to load('site.html .classforportion') into hidden div and than copy the content into iframe?

Comment: that is indeed one solution I was thinking about, however I'm not toatally 100 on how to copy past content by javascript into an iframe...

I think (and do correct me if I'm wrong!) the only way to load content into a iframe is by specifying a 'src' in the <iframe> tag...

Comment: @Matte         Yes, but than, after the content is loaded and if it is from the same domain, you can access it and get just what you want from iframe.